# Why I am getting error when I try to cast an opencv image data pointer to a char*

Tags: c++, opencv

I have this code:

```
cv::Mat myImage = imread("Image.png");
char * dataPointer = const_cast<char*>(myImage.data);
```

but I am getting error:

```
'const_cast' : cannot convert from 'uchar *const ' to 'char *'
```

Why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the issue is that a `const_cast` can only change the CV-qualifiers, and a cast from `uchar *const` to `char *` does a bit more than that: it will also convert `unsigned char` (aliased by OpenCV to `uchar`) to `char`, pointer-wise.

I would advise you not to remove the const qualifier. But if you cannot avoid it, converting the pointer to `uchar*` instead should work for you.

```
cv::Mat myImage = imread("Image.png");
uchar * dataPointer = const_cast<uchar*>(myImage.data);
```

If you really want a `char*`, that can be done too.

```
char* dp = reinterpret_cast<char*>(dataPointer);
```